# Appium Java, How to use specific pageFactory requirement

Tags: java, appium, findby

I have a `pageFactory` class:

```
public class screenFactory {
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "itemFilm")
    public List<MobileElement> listMovies;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "tvTitle")
    public List<MobileElement> listTvTitle;
}
```

Each `itemFilm` contains `tvTitle` (and sometime it doesn't).

Question: how can I check this using only `pageFactory`?

Lets assume situation1:

```
screenFactory.listMovies.size() equals 6;
screenFactory.listTvTitles.size() equals 6;
```

then everything is fine!

Lets assume situation2:

```
screenFactory.listMovies.size() equals 6;
screenFactory.listTvTitles.size() equals 4;
```

then we have a problem, how to detect which elements of `listMovies` contains `tvTitles` as child and which of them don't ?

In other words, having two `List<MobileElement>`, is there a way to compare elements as `MobileElement` for Child/Parent feature ?

Problem comes from requirements not to use `By.id("id")` or other locators in main function but use `screenFactory` only !

If I use in `screenFactory` this:

```
@HowToUseLocators(androidAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.CHAIN)
@AndroidFindBy(id = "itemFilm")
@AndroidFindBy(id = "tvTitle")
public List<MobileElement> listTvTitle;
```

it doesn't work again, cos in situation#2 from above it will give me the same:

```
screenFactory.listMovies.size() equals 6;
screenFactory.listTvTitles.size() equals 4;
```

Comment: Can you provide an inspector view of your application? It's difficult to impossible to suggest how to associate the two object types without seeing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the inspector view of your application, the only recommendation I can give is to have your developers provide parent information in the content-description of the TV Title objects. You then have the association you need to match the two objects.

You'd then iterate through each movie title and for each check the entire list of TV Titles for a content-description that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I just wanted to get rid of FindElement:

```
screenFactory.listMovies.get(i).FindElement(By.id("TvTitles"))
```

but seems thats impossible ....

Comment: Correct, because the Movie objects do not contain the TV objects.